# How to change WezTerm color scheme based on current hostname

Tags: terminal

It is possible to change the color scheme for WezTerm in a terminal tab based on the host I am currently logged in? I would like to use a light color schemes by default, but to have it change to a dark color scheme when I ssh to certain hosts.